# Do i need to unlock blackberry mobile to install apps outside of BB Appworld?

Tags: blackberry, cordova, phonegap-build

I developed an app with PhoneGap for BlackBerry and when I try to install this app onto a  device, it show some text like:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
RIM-COD-URL-80: HELLOWORLD-80.cod
MIDlet-Jar-Size: 3757417
RIM-MIDlet-Icon-2-1: ____HOVER_ICON_resources/icon_hover.png,focused
RIM-COD-URL-79: HELLOWORLD-79.cod
RIM-COD-URL-78: HELLOWORLD-78.cod
RIM-COD-URL-77: HELLOWORLD-77.cod
RIM-COD-URL-76: HELLOWORLD-76.cod
RIM-COD-Size-80: 64944
RIM-COD-URL-75: HELLOWORLD-75.cod
RIM-COD-URL-74: HELLOWORLD-74.cod
RIM-COD-URL-73: HELLOWORLD-73.cod
MicroEdition-Configuration: CLDC-1.1
RIM-COD-URL-72: HELLOWORLD-72.cod
RIM-COD-URL-71: HELLOWORLD-71.cod
RIM-COD-URL-70: HELLOWORLD-70.cod
RIM-COD-Size-79: 45632
RIM-COD-Size-78: 38008
RIM-COD-Size-77: 53040
MIDlet-Version: 0.1.1
RIM-COD-Size-76: 51536
RIM-COD-Size-75: 51536
RIM-COD-Size: 69408
RIM-COD-Size-74: 51536
RIM-COD-URL-69: HELLOWORLD-69.cod
RIM-COD-Size-73: 51532
RIM-COD-URL-68: HELLOWORLD-68.cod
RIM-COD-Size-72: 51532
RIM-COD-URL-67: HELLOWORLD-67.cod
RIM-COD-Size-71: 54824
RIM-COD-URL-66: HELLOWORLD-66.cod
RIM-COD-Size-70: 55148
RIM-COD-URL-65: HELLOWORLD-65.cod
RIM-COD-URL-64: HELLOWORLD-64.cod
RIM-COD-URL-63: HELLOWORLD-63.cod
RIM-COD-URL-62: HELLOWORLD-62.cod
RIM-COD-URL-61: HELLOWORLD-61.cod
RIM-COD-URL-60: HELLOWORLD-60.cod
RIM-MIDlet-Flags-1: 0
MIDlet-Name: HELLO WORLD
RIM-COD-Size-69: 51436
RIM-COD-Size-68: 51436
RIM-COD-Size-67: 51436
RIM-COD-Size-66: 51436
RIM-COD-Size-65: 51436
RIM-COD-Size-64: 51436
RIM-COD-URL-59: HELLOWORLD-59.cod
RIM-COD-Size-63: 51416
RIM-COD-URL-58: HELLOWORLD-58.cod
RIM-COD-Size-62: 51416
RIM-COD-URL-57: HELLOWORLD-57.cod
RIM-COD-Size-61: 56940
RIM-COD-URL-56: HELLOWORLD-56.cod
RIM-COD-Size-60: 51340
RIM-COD-URL-55: HELLOWORLD-55.cod
RIM-COD-URL-54: HELLOWORLD-54.cod
RIM-COD-URL-53: HELLOWORLD-53.cod
RIM-COD-URL-52: HELLOWORLD-52.cod
RIM-COD-URL-51: HELLOWORLD-51.cod
RIM-COD-URL-50: HELLOWORLD-50.cod
RIM-MIDlet-Icon-Count-2: 1
RIM-MIDlet-Icon-Count-1: 1
RIM-COD-Size-59: 56428
RIM-COD-Size-58: 56012
RIM-COD-Size-57: 51348
RIM-COD-Size-56: 51344
RIM-COD-URL-9: HELLOWORLD-9.cod
RIM-COD-Size-55: 59132
RIM-COD-URL-8: HELLOWORLD-8.cod
RIM-COD-Size-54: 51460
RIM-COD-URL-49: HELLOWORLD-49.cod
RIM-COD-URL-7: HELLOWORLD-7.cod
RIM-COD-Size-53: 51460
RIM-COD-URL-48: HELLOWORLD-48.cod
RIM-COD-URL-6: HELLOWORLD-6.cod
MicroEdition-Profile: MIDP-2.0
RIM-COD-Size-52: 51460
RIM-COD-URL-47: HELLOWORLD-47.cod
RIM-COD-URL-5: HELLOWORLD-5.cod
RIM-COD-Size-51: 51440
RIM-COD-URL-46: HELLOWORLD-46.cod
RIM-COD-URL-4: HELLOWORLD-4.cod
RIM-COD-Size-50: 51440
RIM-COD-URL-45: HELLOWORLD-45.cod
RIM-COD-URL-3: HELLOWORLD-3.cod
RIM-COD-URL-44: HELLOWORLD-44.cod
RIM-COD-URL-2: HELLOWORLD-2.cod
RIM-COD-URL-43: HELLOWORLD-43.cod
RIM-COD-URL-1: HELLOWORLD-1.cod
RIM-COD-URL-42: HELLOWORLD-42.cod
RIM-COD-URL-41: HELLOWORLD-41.cod
RIM-COD-Size-9: 48440
RIM-COD-URL-40: HELLOWORLD-40.cod
RIM-COD-Size-8: 56444
RIM-COD-Size-7: 67932
RIM-COD-Size-6: 74336
RIM-COD-Size-5: 63684
RIM-COD-Size-4: 64960
RIM-COD-Size-3: 66384
RIM-COD-Size-2: 74136
RIM-COD-Size-1: 71816
RIM-COD-Size-49: 57512
RIM-COD-Size-48: 59124
RIM-COD-Size-47: 55580
RIM-COD-Size-46: 51464
RIM-COD-Size-45: 51464
RIM-COD-Size-44: 51464
RIM-COD-URL-39: HELLOWORLD-39.cod
RIM-COD-Size-43: 51460
RIM-COD-URL-38: HELLOWORLD-38.cod
RIM-COD-Size-42: 51460
RIM-COD-URL-37: HELLOWORLD-37.cod
RIM-COD-URL-36: HELLOWORLD-36.cod
RIM-COD-Size-41: 51332
RIM-COD-URL-35: HELLOWORLD-35.cod
RIM-COD-Size-40: 51464
RIM-COD-URL-34: HELLOWORLD-34.cod
RIM-COD-URL-33: HELLOWORLD-33.cod
RIM-COD-URL-32: HELLOWORLD-32.cod
RIM-COD-URL-31: HELLOWORLD-31.cod
RIM-COD-URL-30: HELLOWORLD-30.cod
RIM-COD-Module-Dependencies: net_rim_cldc,net_rim_bb_web_jse_api,net_rim_xml_org,net_rim_bb_browser_field2_api,net_rim_os,net_rim_bbapi_phone,net_rim_bbapi_mailv2,net_rim_bbapi_push,net_rim_bbapi_messagelist,net_rim_pdap,net_rim_bbapi_invoke,net_rim_bbapi_browser,net_rim_networkapi,net_rim_bb_browser_field_api,net_rim_xml,net_rim_locationapi
RIM-COD-SHA1-80: fa 1c 6a 70 fc d8 2d a5 87 ff c0 66 12 42 09 98 69 ee 2e d6
MIDlet-Vendor: Unknown
RIM-COD-Size-39: 52752
RIM-COD-Size-38: 55956
RIM-COD-Size-37: 52452
RIM-COD-Size-36: 51364
RIM-COD-Size-35: 58756
RIM-COD-URL-29: HELLOWORLD-29.cod
RIM-COD-Size-34: 52664
RIM-COD-URL-28: HELLOWORLD-28.cod
RIM-COD-Size-33: 51084
RIM-COD-URL-27: HELLOWORLD-27.cod
RIM-COD-Size-32: 51084
RIM-COD-URL-26: HELLOWORLD-26.cod
RIM-COD-Size-31: 51084
RIM-COD-URL-25: HELLOWORLD-25.cod
RIM-COD-Size-30: 51084
```

So do we need to unlock the device like windows 7 phone?  My device is Blackberry Curve 9220

Answer (score 1):

BlackBerry OS doesn't have the notion of a "developer unlock" the way Windows Phone does. All devices are the same.

You have a couple of options:
1. Only use APIs that do not require a signature.  If you do this, then you can deploy your app to any device without any special treatment.
2. Use RIM's special APIs, and get a code signing key.  To deploy the app with use of the special RIM APIs, you will need to sign the app. When unsigned, the app can be run on a simulator, but not a real device.

Answer (score 1):

Modify `.htaccess` file of your server and add the following lines to it:

```
AddType text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor .jad
AddType application/vnd.rim.cod .cod
AddType application/java-archive .jar
```

You get text instead of installation process, because your server represents jad-file as a simple text file.

It is not necessary to unlock device before installing your custom application. The only thing you need to keep in mind, that is if you are using signed API, then you need to sign your application before installing it on an actual device.

Apply for signing keys here: http://www.blackberry.com/go/codesigning

You will receive an email with attached signing keys. Follow the instructions in the received email to install these keys and use them to sign your application.